# You are not authorised to view this resource - Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 2.5.9 version, and I would like Joomla to redirect me to the login page if I am not logged in when i click an article which the **Permission Access** is for Registered only, but instead Joomla returns me this message: You are not authorised to view this resource.

And I dont see any reason why joomla by default havent made it redirect to login page.

Thanks

Comment: Becasue doing that wouldn't send a proper status header. Further, what's the guarantee that the user will be able to see it if they login?  If you use show not authorized you will get a link to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but I think it's a good workaround. I'm working on the same issue. My approach at the moment is to check the messages for the "not authorised" string, and then set a flag based on that. You can then check that flag anywhere in template and either redirect, or just choose to optionally show the login form.`

```
/* get message from app */
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$messages = $app->getMessageQueue();

/* set login flag to 0 */
$showlogin = 0;

/* if there is a message set... */
if (isset($messages[0])) {

    /* loop through messages and check for the "not authorised" string */
    foreach ($messages as $msg) {

        if ($msg["type"] == "error" && strpos($msg["message"], "not authorised") ) {

            /* if found, update login flag */
            $showlogin = 1;

        }

    }

}


    /* include in template body - you could redirect here instead of including login form */
if ($showlogin) {  ?>

    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login-form" style="none" />

<?php } ?>
```

`

Comment: Hi, where exactly do you copy this chunck of code? I'm kinda new to Joomla so could you be very specific on which file? Thanks !

Comment: @fabdarice I'm using this code in the index.php file for my template, just before the beginning of HTML output (right before you see `<!DOCTYPE html>`). The index.php file is in the root folder of your template - /templates/your_template/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you try to access an article which is not visible, but the category is publically visible.

Seems like it is not considered a bug, but I think its a pretty unexpected "feature".

To fix this you can edit:

> joomla/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php

```
    // Check the view access to the article (the model has already computed the values).
    if ($item->params->get('access-view') == false && ($item->params->get('show_noauth', '0') == '0'))
    {
        $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'), 'error');
        $uri = urlencode(base64_encode(JURI::getInstance()->toString()));
        JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(
            JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return='. $uri, false)
        );
        return;
    }
```

This will show the login screen and return to the article after a succesfull login.

If you dont want to edit the core file (because you want to update your system), you have to create a system plugin to override this.